# Floating buttons in HTML

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get a floating navigation bar done where it always shows just one button and on click it would open up the rest under it. I am using bootstrap collapse and collapse show classes . With this it should be working like on the click on first button it would show the rests and when you click on it again it should minimize and not show the other buttons under it.Below is the code for it.

```css
#presentation {
  width: 480px;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #FFF;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  transition: all 0.3s;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#presentation:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  transition: all 0.3s;
  transform: translateZ(10px);
}

#floating-button {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: gray;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #666;
}

.plus {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 55px;
  font-size: 38px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-weight: 300;
  animation: plus-out 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#container-floating {
  position: fixed;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 50px;
}

#container-floating:hover {
  height: 400px;
  width: 90px;
  padding: 30px;
}

#container-floating:hover .plus {
  animation: plus-in 0.15s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.edit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: auto;
  line-height: 65px;
  transform: rotateZ(-70deg);
  transition: all 0.3s;
  animation: edit-out 0.3s;
}

#container-floating:hover .edit {
  animation: edit-in 0.2s;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes edit-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotateZ(-70deg);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes edit-out {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotateZ(-70deg);
  }
}

@keyframes plus-in {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotateZ(180deg);
  }
}

@keyframes plus-out {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotateZ(180deg);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}

.nds {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 300;
  transform: scale(0);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nd1 {
  background: gray;
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 120px;
 /*  animation-delay: 0.2s;
  animation: bounce-out-nds 0.3s linear;*/
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  } 

.nd3 {
  background: #3c80f6;
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 180px;
 /*  animation-delay: 0.15s;
  animation: bounce-out-nds 0.15s linear;*/
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
}

.nd4 {
  background: #ba68c8;
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 240px;
  /* animation-delay: 0.1s;
  animation: bounce-out-nds 0.1s linear;*/
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
}

.nd5 {
  background-image: url('https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-X-aQXHatDQY/Uy86XLOyEdI/AAAAAAAAAF0/TBEZvkCnLVE/w140-h140-p/fb3a11ae-1fb4-4c31-b2b9-bf0cfa835c27');
  background-size: 100%;
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 300px;
  animation-delay: 0.08s;
  animation: bounce-out-nds 0.1s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes bounce-nds {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes bounce-out-nds {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}

#container-floating:checked {  
  margin-top:0;
  opacity:1;
}

#container-floating:hover .nds {
  animation: bounce-nds 0.1s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#container-floating:hover .nd3 {
  animation-delay: 0.08s;
}

#container-floating:hover .nd4 {
  animation-delay: 0.15s;
}

#container-floating:hover .nd5 {
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.letter {
  font-size: 23px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.reminder {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.profile {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="container-floating">
<div id="floatingnav" class="collapse show">
    <div class="nd1 nds" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left">
   <i id="locateplace" class="fa fa-search fa-stack-1x fa-inverse fa-2x" style="top:12px" ng-click="navMenuController($event);" role="button" tabindex="0"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="nd3 nds" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left">
   <i id="locateplace" class="fa fa-search fa-stack-1x fa-inverse fa-2x" style="top:12px" ng-click="navMenuController($event);" role="button" tabindex="0"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="nd4 nds" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left">
   <i id="locateplace" class="fa fa-search fa-stack-1x fa-inverse fa-2x" style="top:12px" ng-click="navMenuController($event);" role="button" tabindex="0"></i>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="floating-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#floatingnav"  data-placement="left">
        <i id="legend" class="fa fa-tasks fa-stack-1x fa-inverse fa-2x" style="top:12px" role="button" tabindex="0"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's your problem? You need the other buttons to show up when the main button is **clicked not hovered**? When you say "not show the other buttons *under* it", do you mean *above* it? Or they should really appear under the main button?

Comment: When I click on the first button you see it should expand the inner div and show the other icons . And when clicked again  on the first icon the div should collapse .

Answer (score 4):

Plunkr Link - https://plnkr.co/edit/QJgZM57mcvSGsFadsWGC?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link ref="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

  <div id="container-floating">

      <div id="floating-button" type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#floatingnav"  data-placement="left">
        <i id="legend" class="fa fa-tasks fa-stack-1x fa-inverse fa-2x" style="top:12px" role="button" tabindex="0"></i>
    </div>
  <div id="floatingnav" class="collapse">
      <div class="nd1 nds" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left">
     <i id="locateplace" class="fa fa-search fa-stack-1x fa-inverse fa-2x" style="top:12px" ng-click="navMenuController($event);" role="button" tabindex="0"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="nd3 nds" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left">
     <i id="locateplace" class="fa fa-search fa-stack-1x fa-inverse fa-2x" style="top:12px" ng-click="navMenuController($event);" role="button" tabindex="0"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="nd4 nds" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left">
     <i id="locateplace" class="fa fa-search fa-stack-1x fa-inverse fa-2x" style="top:12px" ng-click="navMenuController($event);" role="button" tabindex="0"></i>
      </div>
  </div>

  </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Very nicely done!. However, the borders on the buttons are really annoying, so I suggest @SNT use `.fa:focus {outline:none}`. It makes it look more professional!

Comment: @SankarshMakam : Agree :)  have added the class.

Comment: +I for your answer!

Comment: @YounisArM  This is on hover right. But if I click on the first button it should display the others as it does now and only hide when you click back on the first button again.

Comment: @YounisArM Does this work on click and disappear back on click.